# Windows 8 Upgrade to 8.1

Tags: windows, windows-8, upgrade

I have a Windows 8 Pro machine activated with a Volume License MAK key. I keep getting notifications asking if I would like to upgrade to Windows 8.1 (and I really would), however when I click Upgrade it takes me to the store, and tells me I cannot upgrade this machine.

From researching I found a number of articles saying you cannot upgrade from 8 to 8.1 using a Volume License Key.

I have a MAK for windows 8.1, is there any way for me to upgrade?

Comment: Since you have volume license you will have to go to the system administrators and ask for disc and key for 8.1, 8.1 is separate os o 8

Comment: Ah ok, will it require a full re-install or can I upgrade with the disc?

Comment: you need a 8.1 VL ISO/DVD, insert the ISO/DVD, run setup.exe and select "Upgrade"

Comment: you can upgrade but the upgrade is really a reinstall not a upgrade same with windows 7 the upgrade isn't really an upgrade like it was for xp,2000 etc